# Problemas con Pagina JSF

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Estoy realizando una pequeña prueba de estudio, tengo una pagina `index.xhtml`, la cual contiene un par de `inputText` con un value que estan asociado a unos atributo de la clase `Candidato`, seguidamente el `commandButton` manda a llamar el metodo enviar del backing bean `vacanteForm`, pero cuando relleno los campos y le doy click al boton me sale el siguiente error, y he buscado por la web pero no he podido encontrar la solucion al este error:

- Server: Glassfish 5.0
- Java 1.8
- JSF 2.3
- Eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir tu BackingBean llamado 'candidato'?

Comment: Comparte por favor el código de la clase Candidato.

Comment: ya les pude adjuntar una captura de la clase Candidato

Answer (score 0):

Aqui les adjunto captura de la Clase Candidato
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En tu vista index deberías enlazar los componentes con un controlador y a su vez con la entidad o el pojo candidato de este modo <p:inputText value="#{controlador.candidato.nombre}/>

Answer (score -2):

Parece que "candidato" no es un Bean, aunque sin ver el código no sabría decirte. Comprueba al menos lo siguiente sobre la clase Candidato:

- Implementa *Serializable*
- Contiene la anotación *@Named(value="candidato")*. Podrías estar usando *@ManagedBean*, pero mejor usa *@Named*
- Comprueba que los scopes que apliques (RequestScoped, SessionScoped...) sean del paquete *javax.inject* ó *javax.enterprise.context*

No totalmente necesario pero recomendable:

- Incluye un *static final long serialVersionUID*
- Un constructor vacío
- Inicializa el bean en un método con *@PostConstruct*, no en el constructor

Comment: Rafael habría que esperar a que comparta el código, dado que esto le puede servir a alguien más.

Comment: En la parte de arriba ya les adjunte captura de la clase Candidato